# How to use type ahead text box in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use a text box like drop down.

Means if I will write something on the text box then the text box should be filled according to the search text.

Comment: Like an autocomplete feature ? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @Chidananda Behera - Thats called as an auto complete text box.

Comment: Bootstrap had 1 typeahead, now it's separated  https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several Jquery plugins availble to convert a textbox or dropdown to typeahead textbox.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out JqueryUI's autocomplete component? Take a look [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).